# Flutter: "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe" in a Stateless Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, progressdialog

I am new to Flutter, and this problem really bothers me, I has searched through the Internet, however, none of the results satisfies me:

I try to use Progress Dialog from the package:

`import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';`

And the class `MyApp` in my `main.dart` file is like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Declare and decorate my Progress Dialog.
    ProgressDialog pr = ProgressDialog(
      context,
      type: ProgressDialogType.Normal,
      isDismissible: false,
    );
    pr.style(
      message: 'Fetching Something...',
      borderRadius: 50.0,
      elevation: 5.0,
    );

    // TODO: implement build method
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RaisedButton.icon(
          onPressed: () async {
            pr.show();
            await fetchData();
            pr.hide();
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          label: Text('Fetch Data'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my example `fetchData()` function is like this (of course the package and installation steps for Firestore's functions are validated):

```
Future<void> fetchData() async {
  // Just an example of really fetching something.
  await Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .document('0')
      .delete();
}
```

What I want is that, every time I click the button, a loading spinner is showed and hides immediately after `fetchData()` function finishes. This yields a correct flow in the first click, however, if I click the button for the second time, the spinner is not show (the `fetchData()` function still executes properly). And a warning (not an error) is displayed in the Terminal:

```
I/flutter (17942): Exception while showing the dialog
I/flutter (17942): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
I/flutter (17942): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
I/flutter (17942): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

The documents on `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` are quite limited and difficult to understand. So I still have no idea of how to solve this problem correctly.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please, look at the example tab in the progress_dialog package on pub.dev.
You should move that `ProgressDialog pr = ...` implementation outside the myApp, inside another widget, and then call it as shown in the example code

Comment: This is just a demo sir, my actual code contains the ProgressDialog in another widget, very much alike to the example, and yet, the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `await pr.show();` and `await pr.hide();` 
code snippet

```
onPressed: () async {
        await pr.show();
        await fetchData();
        await pr.hide();
      },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProgressDialog pr = ProgressDialog(
      context,
      type: ProgressDialogType.Normal,
      isDismissible: false,
    );
    pr.style(
      message: 'Fetching Something...',
      borderRadius: 50.0,
      elevation: 5.0,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await pr.show();
                await fetchData();
                await pr.hide();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              label: Text('Fetch Data'),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```